# get the answer of a mysql request

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, stripe-payments

I am coding a website implementing stripe API.
I am using NodeJS and mysql.
I need to create 2 tables to save multiple informations.

I have a an ID in one table and an authID in the 2nd table.
I am trying to make link the 2 tables with those ID so i can easily link them together.
So i created a variable that saves the ID of the first table and puts it into the 2. But I can't manage to save it.

here is my code:

```
        var sqlstripe = "SELECT id FROM authentification WHERE customerID = '" + customer.id +"'";
    console.log("getting ID from auth to put it in stripeID");
    var rowIDinDB = DB.query(sqlstripe, function (err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(result);
    });

    var sqlInsertstrip = "INSERT INTO stripeid (authID, customerID, subscriptionID, amount, date) VALUES ?";
    var valuesstripe = [
        [rowIDinDB, customer.id, subscription.id, subscription.amount, datenow]
    ];
    console.log('sending data to the DB for StripeID table');
    DB.query(sqlInsertstrip, [valuesstripe], function (err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(result);
    });
```

I save the request in "sqlstripe", but when I post it under rowIDinDB, I get : 
Error: ER_TRUNCATED_WRONG_VALUE_FOR_FIELD: Incorrect integer value: '[object Object]' for column 'authID' at row 1

auth ID is a smallint unsigned, ID aswell.

thank you for your help if you know how to fix

Comment: I am not sure which package you are using, but generally `DB.query()` is an asynchronous call and will return a promise; what you could do is to put the insertion in the callback function `DB.query(sqlstripe, function (err, result) {` and use the result as the `id` or you could use `Promisify` or `async await` to get the result.

Comment: i don't use promise anymore. I use the newest version. forgot which one.

Answer (score 0):

The comment is a bit difficult to add code, so putting a reply here.
Since you are not using Promise as you mentioned, you will need to put your code in the callback.

Disclaimer, i have not tested it as not sure which package you are using. But the idea is `rowIDinDB` is not the result you are looking for, it is in the result callback.

```
var sqlstripe =
  "SELECT id FROM authentification WHERE customerID = '" + customer.id + "'";
console.log("getting ID from auth to put it in stripeID");
DB.query(sqlstripe, function(err, result) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(result);

  let rowIDinDB = result.rows; // ????? Attention, depends on your library, to USE the RIGHT properties

  var sqlInsertstrip =
    "INSERT INTO stripeid (authID, customerID, subscriptionID, amount, date) VALUES ?";
  var valuesstripe = [
    [rowIDinDB, customer.id, subscription.id, subscription.amount, datenow]
  ];
  console.log("sending data to the DB for StripeID table");
  DB.query(sqlInsertstrip, [valuesstripe], function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
  });
});
```